# ANTLR: code generation target requires ANTLR 4.7; it can't be loaded by the current ANTLR 1.0

Tags: antlr4

I have a problem with ANTLR4, (ANother Tool for Language Recognition) when trying to build a new target for PHP7.

First I purged the installed ANTLR3 package with

```
apt-get remove --purge antlr antlr-doc libantlr3-runtime-java libantlr-java
```

from the Debian Linux box I am using.

Then I forked and cloned the project ANTLR4 from github, programmed a new runtime PHP7, created a new class PHP7Target as a subclass of class Target and wrote a fitting PHP7.stg.

Then I rebuilt ANTLR4 with

```
cd antlr4
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1G
mvn clean    
mvn -DskipTests=true install
```

Using the grammar T.g4

```
grammar T;

a
    : 'b'   #alt1
    | 'c'   #alt2
    ;

b : 'x' | 'y' {} ;

e : e '*' e
  | 'foo'
  ;
```

Trying to run ANTLR4 with

```
export CLASSPATH=~/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4/4.7.1-SNAPSHOT/antlr4-4.7.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH
cd ~/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4/4.7.1-SNAPSHOT
java -jar ./antlr4-4.7.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar /tmp/T.g4 -Dlanguage=PHP7
```

I ran into the error

```
error(35):  PHP7 code generation target requires ANTLR 4.7; it can't be loaded by the current ANTLR 1.0
```

The error displays two times.

Without the option -Dlanguage=PHP7 ANTLR will do its job and create the java-files for the grammar.

Unfortunately I do not understand the error message. It seems, that an old ANTLR version is in use by the package and I do not know how to upgrade ANTLR to version 4 in this case.

Can anybody help and tell me where my error is, please?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

In the file PHP7target.java there is a method called getVersion(). This function should not return the version of the runtime (ie "1.0") but the version of ANTLR ("4.7")